# CMake add header files to target

Tags: c++, cmake

I know that this is a silly question, but I am new to c++ and it's development environment and I want to learn it the right way.

I am trying to learn how CMake works. Using CLion (which dynamically generated the `CMakeList.txt`), I saw that when a class is created, both the `.cpp` and `.h` are added to the target executable. But when removing the `.h` file from the `add_executable` call, the code compiled just fine, even tho in `main.cpp` there was a `#include` reference to that header file.

My question is if adding headers to the target executable is optional or not? I normally use VSCode which doesn't generate the `CMakeList.txt` for me and I wouldn't want to make a habit of not including headers to the target executable if I am supposed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_executable` simply takes a list of files which it passes on to the compiler. The compiler ignores any file with a conventional header suffix (maybe all suffixes that it doesn't recognise as source file). As such, it is not necessary to list header files, nor will listing them cause problems - as far as compilation is concerned.

Some IDE may use the listed header files for some internal purposes. I'm not sure if Clion does; its behaviour may be to facilitate the use of another IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I believe you're supposed to

```
SET_SOURCE_FILE_PROPERTIES(${header_files} PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY ON)
```

then

```
LIST (APPEND ${project_sources} ${header_files})
```

. Compile with ${project_sources}.